# Repeat factor elements

Tags: r

I want to repeat a factor as illustrated below: I am not sure if this can be done using the `rep()` function?

input:

```
c("100G","105G","302G")
```

out:

```
c("100G","100G","100G","100G","100G","105G","105G","105G","105G","105G","302G","302G","302G","302G","302G")
```

Comment: The `rep` can take a couple of options i.e. either `each` or `times`  If we are going to use `times`, the length should be the same as the initial vector. `rep(v1, times = c(5, 6, 7))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done as:

```
inputVec <- c("100G","105G","302G")
outputVec <- rep(inputVec, each = 5)
outputVec
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this can be done ...

This should do the trick:

```
rep(c("100G","105G","302G"), each=10)
```